# Condicional em clausula MYsql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um `select` normal

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela_Z WHERE condicoes
```

Gostaria de nessa `query` acrescentar um campo que é outra `query`.

```
SELECT 
   campo1,
   campo2,
   campo3,
   (SE houver o id X na TABELA _, = true, caso contrario = false) 
FROM tabela_Z
WHERE condicoes
```

Como fazer isso?

Seria algo dessa forma que eu preciso:

```
SELECT  
   membros.idMembro,
   membros.nome,
   membros.apelido,
   membros.bloqueado,
   membros.usuario,
   membros.senha,
   acessos.idAcesso,
   acessos.nome
   (SELECT IF(admins.idMembro=1, 's', 'n') FROM admins)
FROM membros , acessos, acessosmembros
WHERE 
   membros.usuario ='caca' AND 
   membros.senha ='aaaa' AND
   acessosmembros.idMembro = membros.idMembro AND
   acessosmembros.idAcesso = acessos.idAcesso
```

Se eu fizer

```
SELECT IF(admins.idMembro=1, 's', 'n') FROM admins
```

No **phpmyadmin**, tenho retorno correto.

Mas preciso inserir em uma das **selects** da **query**

Comment: Esse tal `id X` está na mesma tabela? Se houver mais de um resultado na consulta, todos irão retornar o mesmo `true` ou `false` já que na consulta será passado apenas um `id X`, certo?

Comment: pesquise por MySQL IF() function  exemplo https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp veja também https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

Comment: esse id x não está na mesma tabela. É meio que para acrescentar um campo ao Array que vai ser populado pelo resultado dessa query

Comment: acrescentei detalhes à pergunta!

Comment: deu certo, faltou uma virgula no final de    acessos.nome

Answer (score 0):

Como você falou em comentário, faltou uma vírgula após o penúltimo campo do *select*. Pra deixar a consulta mais dinâmica, alterei a condição de validação, checando se o *id* da *subquery* é igual ao da principal (`admins.idMembro=acessosmembros`); assim, terá o valor correto para cada usuário retornado (sem precisar modificar a consulta a cada pesquisa).

```
SELECT  
   membros.idMembro,
   membros.nome,
   membros.apelido,
   membros.bloqueado,
   membros.usuario,
   membros.senha,
   acessos.idAcesso,
   acessos.nome,
   (SELECT IF(admins.idMembro=acessosmembros,idMembro, 's', 'n') FROM admins)
FROM membros, acessos, acessosmembros
WHERE 
   membros.usuario ='caca' AND 
   membros.senha ='aaaa' AND
   acessosmembros.idMembro = membros.idMembro AND
   acessosmembros.idAcesso = acessos.idAcesso
```